# Keras, append to logs from callback

Tags: logging, callback, keras

I have a callback that computes a couple of additional metrics in `on_epoch_end` for validation data and every 10 epochs for test data.

I also have a `CSVLogger` callback that saves normal metrics to a log file.

Is there an easy way from my callback to add a column or two to the logs that gets properly written by `CSVLogger`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can insert your additional metrics into the dictionary `logs`.

```py
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class ComputeMetrics(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        logs['val_metric'] = epoch ** 2  # replace it with your metrics
        if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:
            logs['test_metric'] = epoch ** 3  # same
        else:
            logs['test_metric'] = np.nan
```

Just remember to place this callback before `CSVLogger` in your `fit` call. Callbacks that appear later in the list would receive a modified version of `logs`. For example,

```py
model = Sequential([Dense(1, input_shape=(10,))])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(np.random.rand(100, 10),
          np.random.rand(100),
          epochs=30,
          validation_data=(np.random.rand(100, 10), np.random.rand(100)),
          callbacks=[ComputeMetrics(), CSVLogger('1.log')])
```

Now if you take a look at the output log file, you'll see two additional columns `test_metric` and `val_metric`:

```py
epoch,loss,test_metric,val_loss,val_metric
0,0.547923130989,nan,0.370979120433,0
1,0.525437340736,nan,0.35585285902,1
2,0.501358469725,nan,0.341958616376,4
3,0.479624577463,nan,0.329370084703,9
4,0.460121934414,nan,0.317930338383,16
5,0.440655426979,nan,0.307486981452,25
6,0.422990380526,nan,0.298160370588,36
7,0.406809270382,nan,0.289906248748,49
8,0.3912438941,nan,0.282540213466,64
9,0.377326357365,729,0.276457450986,81
10,0.364721306562,nan,0.271435074806,100
11,0.353612961769,nan,0.266939682364,121
12,0.343238875866,nan,0.263228923082,144
13,0.333940329552,nan,0.260326927304,169
14,0.325931007862,nan,0.25773427248,196
15,0.317790198028,nan,0.255648627281,225
16,0.310636150837,nan,0.25411529541,256
17,0.304091459513,nan,0.252928718328,289
18,0.298703012466,nan,0.252127869725,324
19,0.292693507671,6859,0.251701972485,361
20,0.287824733257,nan,0.251610517502,400
21,0.283586999774,nan,0.251790778637,441
22,0.27927801609,nan,0.252100949883,484
23,0.276239238977,nan,0.252632959485,529
24,0.273072380424,nan,0.253150621653,576
25,0.270296501517,nan,0.253555388451,625
26,0.268056542277,nan,0.254015884399,676
27,0.266158599854,nan,0.254496408701,729
28,0.264166412354,nan,0.254723013639,784
29,0.262506003976,24389,0.255338237286,841
```

Comment: Gosh, you were first. Congratulations :)

Comment: I admittedly could have tried this myself :-D just wanted to be sure messing with the logs "on-the-fly" wouldn't upset anything in keras. Also nice to know the order of the callbacks matters.

Comment: Ha :) There are actually two callbacks being appended implicitly to the callback list (and thus might be affected), `History` and `ProgbarLogger`. But as far as I know they should be able to handle (or ignore) the additional values.

Comment: Appending a metric that is not a scalar, like a confusion matrix, appears to be not supported. Has anyone found a solution to that?

Comment: What determines what metrics are shown on the command line during `verbose=1`? What if I save some metrics into the `logs` and they are numpy arrays, or not single numbers?