# In the TensorFlow Keras API, how can I add parameters to the csv file created by CSVLogger callback?

Tags: tensorflow, logging, deep-learning, callback, tf.keras

How can I create a TensorFlow Keras API callback that, for every epoch, will add the learning rate value to the csv file created by tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger?

With the callback below I can print out my learning rate after each epoch, and add it to the history. But I can't figure out how to have it added to the CSVLogger csv file. It seems there is a log dict stored somewhere, which holds the values printed by CSVLogger, but I don't understand where it is or how to add to it.

```py
class Print_lr(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print('lr = %f' % self.model.optimizer.lr)
        if 'lr' not in self.model.history.history.keys():
            self.model.history.history['lr'] = []
        self.model.history.history['lr'].append(self.model.optimizer.lr.numpy())
```

Comment: By default I believe it already includes the learning rate. My test shows `epoch;accuracy;loss;lr;val_accuracy;val_loss` as the values logged. However if you do require custom logging, consider a [LambdaCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037721/8471799). More examples in the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/lambda_callback/).

Comment: Thanks, @cddt. I've never seeing lr in my history or in the CSVLogger csv file. Are you using a LearningRateScheduler callback? Thanks for the LambdaCallback idea. Not exactly what I was hoping for, but it might suffice. Will try it out.

Comment: You're right, I was using `ReduceLROnPlateau`. I'm not sure whether that's an option for you.

Comment: It is, @cddt. So I tried using ```ReduceLROnPlateau``` but the ``lr`` still didn't appear in the ```CSVLogger``` csv file. I've tried TF 2.1 and 2.3. What version are you using?

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488549/keras-append-to-logs-from-callback